# How can I fix etckeeper or uninstall it so apt will install / remove new packages?

Tags: debian, apt, lxc, etckeeper

OS: Debian Buster 10.10 inside [lxc](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lxc)

I am attempting to install a new package (I tried different packages) and apt (and DPkg) is complaining with the following error message(s):

```
/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: 1: /etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: Files: not found
/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: 2: /etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: etc.: not found
/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: 3: /etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: uncommitted: not found
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'if [ -x /usr/bin/etckeeper ]; then etckeeper pre-install; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I decided to unstall etckeeper and got the exact same error message.

My googling / searching seems to be lacking.  My reasoning is the problem lies with etckeeper, although I could be wrong.

Comment: Read the `README` file.

Comment: This?  https://etckeeper.branchable.com/README/  If so, I'm struggling to understand. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: update with more information found from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/179570/how-to-remove-a-package-which-post-installation-and-pre-removal-script-fails/179676). I renamed the following directories and recreated them:

```
/etc/etckeeper/  
    pre-install.d
    post-install.d  
    unclean.d
```

And it allowed me to install new packages.

If you want to get rid of etckeeper all together:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/etckeeper.*  
rm -rf /usr/share/etckeeper  
rm -rf /etc/default/etckeeper  
rm -rf /etc/init.d/etckeeper  
apt-get purge etckeeper  
mv /usr/bin/etckeeper /usr/bin/etckeeper.bak  
mv /etc/etckeeper/ /etc/etckeeper.bak
```